# Using python subprocess to interact with a command line application that asks data on an unordered way

Tags: python, subprocess

I’m writing a python program that needs interact with another windows console application. I’m using `subprocess` for that but I’m having some troubles because this windows app asks for inputs randomly on every call.

For example:
`app.exe` on first call ask on this order:
Name: input here
Place: input here
Age: input here

`app.exe` on second call ask on this order:
Place: input here
Name: input here
Age: input here

So when I use:
`process = subprocess.Popen("app.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`
Due this random presentation I need to read every line before use `process.stdin.write()` `flush()` and here is the problem, the `process.stdout.readline()` method is blocked since apparently the line does not contain an end-of-line character due the input it is waiting.
I was reading character by character using `process.stdout.readline(1).decode()` but I guess there is a better way to face this.
Please if anyone knows how to deal with this, I will appreciate your help

 Best Regads!

*Update**
Another example
`process.stdout.readline().decode()` read the line if this line is just text and there is no cursor waiting for an input.
For example:
Hi this is the first line on the console.
Enter your name on this line: input_here 
Here the first line is read without issue. But the second it’s not read because is waiting for an input.

Comment: I am assuming, you had created that `app.exe`. Why don't you use `GUI widget` to ask questions in your application rather then asking question it in console.

Comment: @Xitiz app.exe it’s not created by me, that application already exists and is not replaceable. And yes, I use GUI from python (QT). but I need to interact with app.exe

Comment: Now I don't think I understood your question, can you please explain a bit more clearly for me? If possible with example which is not in question already? @Javier are you telling `process.stdout.readline(1).decode()` works for you?

Comment: @Xitiz From a python GUI application when I click on a button the application should launch a command line tool that is installed on the system and provide the data in an interactive way. The problem is that I don’t know what is the order in which this command line tool requests the data. That’s why I need to read the stdout line that is asking for the value and then with some conditionals identify what the tool is asking. Yes with `process.stdout.readline(x).decode()` I can read the x characters of each line and identify what the tool is asking through the console.

Comment: is that working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know this will help you to solve your problem but here's the idea :

```
process.stdout.readline().decode()
```

This line is working for single line perfectly then check one by one, if "Name" is in it or not, "Place" like

```
if "Name" in <>:
    # Something
elif "Place" in <>:
    # Something
else:
    # Something
```

Comment: that was my first suggestion on my code, but `process.stdout.readline().decode()` is not able to read the line when it is waiting for input data.

Comment: Actually, usual your <br> is said is \n in python.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to format the comment. I put it as an update in the question

Comment: Do you note what is the issue now with this update?